# Node.js unique folder for each upload with multer and shortid

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I'm using shortid for a unique id each upload and multer for the post handler.

I'm uploading some input aswell as an image. I'd like for each upload to be stored inside "upload/XXXXX"
I'm generating the unique id on app.post(...) and would like to know how to send this id to multer.

Using a global variable would have it's problems if 2 posts were done at the same time correct?

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', XXXXX)); //Unique id for file is the same as Folder
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, XXXXX); //Unique id
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: Storage
}).single('pic');

//tell express what to do when the route is requested
app.post('/fbshare', function (req, res, next) {
  let ui = shortid();
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.end("Something went wrong!");
    }
    return res.end("File uploaded sucessfully!.");
  });
});
```

How can i passthrough ui to Storage from app.post() ? Or if you have a better solution I'm all ears.

Thank you

---

**Final Solution**

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    fs.mkdir(path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', req.ui), function(){
       callback(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', req.ui));
    });
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, req.ui + file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.indexOf('.'), file.originalname.length));
  }
});

var upload = multer({
  storage: Storage
}).single('pic');

//tell express what to do when the route is requested
app.post('/fbshare', function (req, res, next) {
  req.ui = shortid();
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.end("Something went wrong!");
    }
    return res.end("File uploaded sucessfully!.");
  });
```

});

Comment: Can you not just pass the value through the req object?

Comment: Like replacing one of the fields or appending to req.body?

Comment: Yeah basically what the accepted answer said ;)

Comment: thanks for elaborating the the answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
app.post('/fbshare', function (req, res, next) {
  req.ui = shortid(); // create the id in the request
....
```

then in the multer

```
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, path.join(__dirname, 'uploads', req.ui)); //Unique id for     
....
```

the same with `filename`

Comment: I guess it's my javascript knowledge, didn't know i could just add a field inside an object and it would persist. Also never thought of using the request Object because req.body is empty inside of app.post(). Only on multer can i see the body but req.ui works! I'm guessing I'm not getting the upload done because i should create the folder before trying to move the file there since multer does not create the folder if it isn't there. Hence "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/.../uploads/HyAfAbX7z/HyAfAbX7z'"

Comment: Since i can edit it. Your problem solved my immediate problem :) Which led to another problem being that i needed to use fs.mkdir() before the destination callback.

Comment: In your case, `req.body` was empty before `multer` middleware works its magic, in other non cases the `req` object persist as you pass them into functions because you always pass a reference of an object into a function in javascript. Yes `multer` doesn't create the folder and you should use `mkdirp` instead of `fs.mkdir`.